# List of existing Android Virtual Devices empty

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I'm new to Android development and I'm currently going through some tutorials.  When I setup a new Android Project in Eclipse, and select **Windows** -> **Android SDK and AVD Manager**, in **Virtual Devices**, the list of existing Android Virtual Devices is empty.  *Is it supposed to be?*

From the pictures in the tutorial, it's pre-populated.  Can I download these AVDs from somewhere, am I missing something here?  Also, I'm developing this on my Macbook Pro.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it supposed to be?

Yes.

> From the pictures in the tutorial,
>   it's pre-populated.

The second step of the [Hello, World tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html) has you create an AVD.

> Can I download these AVDs from
>   somewhere, am I missing something
>   here?

No, [you create them](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html#AVD) on your machine using the SDK.

Comment: Thanks!  Considering the amount of Android devices out there, I think it would be nice to have a way to import/export these AVDs.

Comment: The AVDs don't, by default, recreate the exact specs of any particular device. Plus if you want to import/export them (and don't want to just create them via the AVD Manager), just copy the contents of the appropriate ~/.android/avd/ directory.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create them. Simply click on the New button on the right of that screen. See [this documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/avd.html) for details.

Answer (score 2):

Strangely enough - there's no way to import it.
There's a good walk-through including the configurations for popular devices here:
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/common-android-virtual-device-configurations/